# How to remove the filter on only the clicked item in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I am masking the serial numbers by default (using a custom filter in angular). When the user clicks on 1 particular masked serial number, the mask needs to be removed.

Here is my code so far:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';

  $scope.serialNumbers = [
    {serial: 12345678},
    {serial: 22245678},
    {serial: 33345678},
  ];

    }]);

  myApp.filter('mask', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var inputArray = input.toString().split('');
      for (var i = 2, l = inputArray.length; i < l - 2; i++) {
        inputArray[i] = '*'; // replace
      }
      return inputArray.join('');
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      Hello, {{name}}!
      <p>Below are your serial numbers:</p>
      <p ng-repeat="serialNumber in serialNumbers">{{serialNumber.serial | mask}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure I understand issue but you can use an argument in the filter and for simplicity bind it to a property of the object

```
myApp.filter('mask', function() {
    return function(input, noMask) {
      if(noMask){
          return input;
      }
      var inputArray = input.toString().split('');
      for (var i = 2, l = inputArray.length; i < l - 2; i++) {
        inputArray[i] = '*'; // replace
      }
      return inputArray.join('');
    };
  });
```

Then in html do something like:

```
<p ng-repeat="serialNumber in serialNumbers" 
   ng-click="serialNumber.noMask=!serialNumber.noMask">
      {{serialNumber.serial | mask: serialNumber.noMask }}
</p>
```

Comment: You understood it absolutely right! :) I am now thinking if there is a way to keep it unmasked once clicked?

Comment: sure just change to `ng-click="serialNumber.noMask=true"` or create a controller function that does nothing if the object already has that property set